# Using jquery to set asp.net mvc model values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a gap in my understanding. I have two view screens, one successfully gets a value from a devexpress selection grid but one doesn't... and I don't understand what I am doing differently.

When I use firebug I can't find where the model is set in the DOM.

The following works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EtracsWeb.Areas.IO.Models
{
    public class VoyageInputModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Value must be supplied")]
        [Display(Name = "Show Received Voyages")]
        public bool ShowReceivedVoyages { get; set; }

        public string VoyageIDS { get; set; }

    }
}
```

being used in the view (which works)...here is a fragment of the view:

```
@using EtracsWeb.Areas.IO.Models;
@model VoyageInputModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Voyage (Receive/UnReceive/etc..)";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMenu.cshtml";
}

@* MUST go here and NOT at end or code won't work *@
<script type="text/javascript">

    //This is the value from the devExpress Selection Grid...
    function OnSelectionChanged(s, e) {
        s.GetSelectedFieldValues("VoyageID", GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback);
    }

    //This is the value from the InputModel...notice it is different...
    //This is why we need this two step process.
    function GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback(values) {
        //  voyage_ids = values;
        //alert(values);
        document.getElementById('VoyageIDS').value = values;
        //alert(document.getElementById('VoyageIDS').value)
    }
</script>
```

Notice I am getting the value from the OnSelection changed as one variable and setting in the inputModel as different name....this all works...

I am trying to do it with a second view and the code dies where I try to access the variable in the model using a getElementbyID .... originally I was trying to use an int...but I switched it to a string...but neither work....

Where in the heck is the model in the DOM?   How can I use Firebug to view the @model values (from asp.net mvc)???

Any ideas where I went wrong on the second window?

Here is the second inputmodel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EtracsWeb.Areas.Vehicle.Models
{
    public class BookMarkListInputModel
    {
        public string SelectedBookMarkID { get; set; }
        public int                   BookMarkID  { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<BookMark> BookMarks          { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the second view fragment:

```
@using EtracsWeb.Areas.Vehicle.Models
@model BookMarkListInputModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMenu.cshtml";
}

@* MUST go here and NOT at end or code won't work *@
<script type="text/javascript">

    //This is the value used in the DevExpress Selection Grid
    function OnSelectionChanged(s, e) {
        s.GetSelectedFieldValues("BookMarkID", GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback);
    }

    //This is the variable from the InputModel...notice it can be different
    //So we need to have this two step process.
    function GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback(values) {
        alert(values);
        document.getElementById('SelectedBookMarkID').value = values;
        alert(document.getElementById('SelectedBookMarkID').value)
    }


    function Success(data) {
        //   alert(data.ReturnMessage);
        id1.innerHTML = data.ReturnMessage;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "where is the Model in the DOM". The DOM contains the HTML elements from your View. I think you need to read more about ASP.Net and MVC.

Comment: ok....but when in debug...where are the model values coming from? ... I have seen the asp.net classes...but there are a lot of them ....

Comment: It's hard to explain this here. You need to read about MVC and ASP.Net in general. Maybe get some tutorials, examples, etc. You're just not getting the way the framework works.